# Is there a difference between access points in household and in commercial premises?

Tags: wireless-access-point

In terms of hardware design is there any difference between a router in regular household
and router in commercial premises such as fastfood place or a mall ?

To make my question little bit clearer do any of the above need to be switched off to "rest" ?

Comment: The question is too vague, as commercial locations can use consumer hardware. If buying specific commercial branded access points, there can be significant differences between the two, especially in regards to antennas _(concerts and other large gatherings providing WiFi often use high power dB antennas with a coverage area that can exceed 2.5miles)_, whereas access points in hospitals or other locations with a multitude of wireless equipment may use a customized frequency _(as I mentioned, the question is too vague to be definitively answered)_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither commercial nor domestic networking equipment *must* be switched off at any time. They can run for years without issue.

The only slight gain is that power-cycling them every so often can free up any 'stuck' ports or stale DNS entries, etc, so it doesn't hurt to have them switch off then back on again, either for 10 mins overnight, or at weekends. With domestic equipment, this can also clear up some of the tiny memory they have too.

Comment: I've been switching my router off for about 5 mins every month without being sure it has any real benefit to the router. I just went with "gut" feeling about it. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @mr_incredible Unless otherwise customized, routers save logs to their `/tmp` mountpoints on RAM, so simply removing power clears any data stored on RAM _(5m isn't needed)_.

Comment: @tetsujin While powering off once a month will clear the logfiles saved to RAM, stale DNS entries can be resolved by simply modifying the release/renew timeframe of the DHCP server _(usually 24h, but on public hotspots ~15m could be beneficial depending on the subnet's netmask and foot traffic through the location)_